# Air travel: Violating checked luggage size by "just a bit"

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airlines

Following up the discussion on size limitations for [checked luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6024/checked-baggage-size-limits) on airplanes, I would like to ask your **experience** on the following:

What happens if your suitcase meets the weight limitation of the airline, but exceeds their size limitation of "Length+Width+Height = 158cm"?

Example: [This](http://www.samsonite.de/termo-young-spinner-84cm-dusty-coral/product-de.htm) suitcase by a known brand with a length sum of 175cm.

Comment: This will vary a lot by airline, and the clerk who checks your bags. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: @Flimzy What I do want to know: Checked baggage, weight okay, but suitcase some centimetres too large. Ever had witnessed that kind of situation? Then please share your experience, because I'm thinking about buying a new suitcase and I want to go as big as air travel let's me _de facto_, not just according to their regulations.

Comment: No, that's not answering my question. What do you want to know? Asking for an opinion poll is not a suitable question. What, specifically, do you want to know?  Which airlines will fudge? How much will they fudge? What's the worst that can happen?

Comment: In all the years I've been flying, I have never seen anyone measure a checked bag.

Comment: Um, this question totally isn't objective. It's a poll. @MarkMayo thoughts?

Comment: If your bag doesn't look insanely huge or heavy, you'll *usually* get away with it, in my experience. You're more likely to get away with over-heavy (pack your anvils in carry-on) than grossly over-size if you can stifle your grimaces.

Comment: Asking people to share their experiences comes under polling in the [faq] and is considered off-topic. I'd highly recommend you reword or edit your question to a SPECIFIC question, rather than polling people.

Comment: @MarkMayo Technically, the question is about travel and thereby on-topic and the FAQ you linked does not say anything about "polling" at all. I can rather see it match "Questions with too many possible answers".

Comment: @arney: "Questions with too many possible answers" is exactly polling.

Comment: @mindcorrosive Which [meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28disambiguation%29) of polling are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've never seen airlines reject (or charge more) for a bag being slightly too tall. They only check the weight and move on. Now, if your checked baggage is obviously much too long (eg. skis) then your item will have to go to the special handling area. I've travelled in North America, Mexico, Europe, the UK, and South-East Asia if that helps at all.

Comment: I've seen people who have had suitcases that were too large to fit in X-ray machines at quarantine/customs, and ended up having those suitcases manually searched. Not really an issue, but takes more time and is a bit of an inconvenience.